# Ruby/Rails - Converting Google Apps Script to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a bit of trouble converting the following method in a Google App Script to work with Rails:

[Tutorial: Parsing an XML Document](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/XML_tutorial.html)

This is the method I'd like to convert:

```
function parse(txt) {
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt, true);
  var attr = doc.spellcheck;
  if (attr) {
    return "Cannot find actor: " + attr.name;
  }

  var actors = doc.html.head.getElements("actor");      
  var movies = doc.html.head.getElements("movie");

  if (!actors || actors.length ==0) {
    return "no match found";
  }

  var movieIndex = 0;
  var r = '';
  var firstPerson = true;
  for (var i in actors) {
    r = r + actors[i].getText();
    if (movies[movieIndex]) {
      r = r + (firstPerson ? "" : " who") + " was in " +
        movies[movieIndex].getText() + " with ";
    }
    movieIndex++;
    firstPerson = false;
  }

  return r;
}
```

This is what I have so far:

I'm using `Nokogiri` to parse the XML:

```
uri = "http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin%20Bacon&b=#{to.strip.to_hash}&u=1&p=google-apps"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(uri))
```

My attempt at conversion:

```
def parse(doc)

    attr = doc.xpath("//link//actor").first # => "<actor>Miley Cyrus</actor>"

    if (!attr)
        return "Cannot find actor: #{attr}"
    end

    actors = doc.xpath("//link//actor")
    movies = doc.xpath("//link//movie")

    if (!actors || actors.length == 0)
        return "No match found."
    end

    movieIndex = 0
    r = ""
    firstPerson = true

    actors.each do |actor|
        r = r + actor

        if (movies[movieIndex])
            r = r + (firstPerson ? "" : " who") + " was in #{movies[movieIndex]} with "
        end

        movieIndex++
        firstPerson = false;
    end

    return r
end
```

I get an error:

```
`block in parse': undefined method `+@' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is happening on the `firstPerson = false` line.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've updated with errors.

Comment: nah, not really. Keep tracing and debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`actors.each` yields each actor node to the block. So your `i` variable contains an actor element (`Nokogiri::XML::Element`). Thus `actors[i]` doesn't make sense, which is why you get the first error.

You're probably looking for

```
actors.each do |actor|
  r = r + actor
  [...]
end
```

although I am not sure what will happen when you attempt to concatenate a `Nokogiri::XML::Element` to a `String`.

Also, `movieIndex++` doesn't do what you hope. You want `movieIndex += 1`.

Although, since you're just incrementing `movieIndex` on every loop, you could remove the line entirely and do `actors.each do |actor, movieIndex|` instead.